# ¿Cómo conectar a un servidor de base de datos en mi misma red?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

hice una aplicacion en python que escribe y lee datos en una base de datos que esta en ell mismo equipo (localhost) y funciona perfectamente el caso es que quiero alojar la BD en otro equipo de mi misma red para lo cual hice exactamente la misma base de dato y la aloje en otra ip pero cuando ejecuto el porgrama me da el siguiente error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'192.168.0.97\' (111 "Connection refused")')
```

yo en el programma solo cambie estas linea:

```
#conexion=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","passroot","kreisdb")
```

por esta:

```
conexion=MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.96","user1","passuser1","kreisdb")
```

sera que tenia que hacer algo mas?
`192.168.0.96` es el IP del otro equipo que quiero conectar

Comment: Y el eqipo esta aceptando conexiones remotas? y por cual puerto? esa cadena no suena a valida.

Comment: en su configuracion active las conexiones remotas y el puerto es 3606 ¿Hay que agregarlas al comando de conexion? ¿cómo?

Comment: no se python, pero podias probar con IP:puerto (192.168.0.96:3606). aunque no puedo asegurar que el puerto vaya ahi

Comment: lo intente en su momento pero arrjaba otro error

Comment: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.0.97:3306' (-2)")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/73749 fijate como lo hacen ahi.. el puerto va en otro campo

Answer (score 0):

Revisa con `nc` si te puede hacer un escaneo sobre ese puerto en ese host, es decir:

```
nc 192.168.0.96 3606
```

Tomo el puerto como el 3606 debido a los comentarios, lo cual se me hace sospechoso, pero supondré que así es lo que deseas.

#### No te aparece nada.

Si no te resulta nada, al parecer tienes que revisar la configuración del servidor de mysql de ese host. Revisa puertos, si está corriendo, si está expuesta esa dirección.

Puedes revisar tu archivo de configuración según tu sistema operativo y/o distribución, en mi caso es un Ubuntu (WSL).

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Y añades la línea;

```
bind-address = 192.168.0.96
port = 3606
```

Comentando con `#` cualquier otra que tenga la clave `bind-address` o `port`. Puedes poner la dirección `0.0.0.0` en lugar de esa ip, para que se pueda exponer el servidor a todas las ip's que tenga disponibles.

Dentro del cliente, pones lo siguiente:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<elige una contraseña>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Y luego reinicias el servidor de mysql, en el caso de que uses algún Linux, sería.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Y desde otra computadora puedes comprobar si está el servidor corriendo en ese puerto con:

```
nc 192.168.0.96 3606
[
5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 ♠   i/h♫♀♦D|☻ §          ¶y=♂&☺479d8j mysql_native_password
```

#### Te responde que no te permite conectarte.

Si te responde algo de la forma `is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`, en el servidor donde está corriendo mysql, entra e ingresa:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<elige una contraseña>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Si revisando con `nc` no te da error alguno y te muestra algo de la forma.

```
    5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 ♠   i/h♫♀♦D|☻ §          ¶y=♂&☺479d8j mysql_native_password
```

Pero tu conexión desde tu script de python te sigue dando error, entonces estás haciendo mal tu conexión en python. Revisa que esté de la forma.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = '192.168.0.96', 
    user = '<el usuario>', 
    passwd = '<contraseña>', 
    db = '<base de datos>', 
    port = 3606)
```

Comment: tengo dos equipo la raspberry con stretch cmo sistema ooperativo y la base de dato esta alojada en la otra coommputadora la cual tiene UBUNTU en el paso de coonfigurar:sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf  no encuentroo ese archivo uso el comando find y encuentro un archivo igual en la carpeta usr/

Comment: Usé ese archivo de configuración como ejemplo, en tu caso puede variar de localización, pero el punto es que tiene que tener esas claves. Pero se me hace raro que no venga en algún archivo dentro de la carpeta `/etc`. Primero revisa lo que arroja el comando `nc` a tu puerto. Pero también revisa lo que haya en la carpeta de de `/etc/mysql`